# Compile Error(C2440)Using CEFbrowser & VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, chromium-embedded

there. I'm new to CEFbrowser.
I'm developing the download model of My CefBrowser.
I've written some code but error while compiling.

```cpp
 class CefClient : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  ///
  // Return the handler for download events. If no handler is returned downloads
  // will not be allowed.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefDownloadHandler> GetDownloadHandler(){
     return this;
  }
```

But VS2015 says C2440:

```cpp
"return":cannot convert from 'CefClient *const' to 'CefRefPtr<CefDownloadHandler>'
```

I'm new. and when i change `return this` to `return null` it runs, but **can't download**.
What can i do to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like your `CefClient` has to inherit from `CefDownloadHandler`, i.e. `class CefClient: public virtual CefBase, public CefDownloadHandler`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57198461/260313

Comment: ok, i'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! this really works. My problem has solved.

Comment: emm, it would be better if you answer this question and i will accept the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. OK, I'll do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `CefClient` has to inherit from `CefDownloadHandler`, i.e. `class CefClient: public virtual CefBase, public CefDownloadHandler`: [CEF C++ Implementing download handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57198461/260313)

Once you inherit from `CefDownloadHandler`, returning `this` from an instance of `CefClient` will fit correctly as a `CefRefPtr<CefDownloadHandler>`.

Comment: great! Thank you!